# Could not load file or assembly system.memory version 4.1.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, aspnetboilerplate

I have asp.net core project which runs on Asp.Net Core V2.1.0 which has signal r integrated. I have downloaded a sample project from aspnetbrolerplate. When I try to run the application it gives me following error.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Can anyone please suggest me possible solution for this issue.

Comment: anything related to this issue reported here https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/252454/systemiofilenotfoundexception-could-not-load-assem.html

Comment: @Fuzzybear I'm running Visual studio 2017 V15.7.4 and have xamrin installed. According to the link provided it says that it should be fixed in V15.7.3 but I don't think it;s fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that this is a [known issue for UWP](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/2406). Update to Asp.Net Core 2.1.1 and [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client NuGet Package to at least 1.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client/), which [has a fix for this UWP issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/306).

Maybe it also fixes your issue.

Comment: I have downloaded 2.1sdk from this link https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks which fixed the issue. Thank you for suggesting for an Upgrade.

Comment: btw, there is a new 2.1 SDK version (2.1.302)

Answer (score 8):

I found installing the `System.Memory` NuGet package resolves the issue.

It is confusing that earliest version is 4.5.1, but if you install it, you will find the assembly versioned a `System.Memory, Version=4.1.0.0`.

For my .NET Framework project I installed NuGet version 4.5.4 which contains `System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1` assembly.

Comment: This was best for me for a winforms framework 4.8 project